# ACF functions not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have added the below code to run at the top of every WordPress page. However, the ACF PHP values are not being called from the advanced custom fields I have created.

How can I call the functions from within the operators?

```
[ux_slider label="destop" hide_nav="true" arrows="false" bullets="false"]

[ux_banner height="100%" video_mp4="<?php the_field('bg_link'); ?>" video_visibility="visible"]

[text_box width="80" margin="100px 0px 0px 0px" position_x="10" position_y="35"]

[button text="$cta_1" color="white" style="outline" size="large" radius="1" expand="0" class="offersbutton"]

[button text="<?php the_field('CTA_2'); ?>" color="white" style="outline" size="large" radius="1" expand="0" class="offersbutton"]


[/text_box]

[/ux_banner]

[/ux_slider]
```

Comment: Just to understand it better, where and how did you placed that code to run on every wordpress page? because it looks quite odd, if you are trying to use shortcode inside a .php file then you are missing the "echo do_shortcode" part. Instead, if that is the content of some widget/page content then your php code will never get executed i guess (expect if there are some weird plugins running)

Comment: @Diego Using the Header & Footer inside Settings, there is an option to add as 'before the page content'. The shortcodes I have added is the code I have grabbed from the page itself using Flatsome theme builder.

Comment: Are you sure that you can write PHP inside your "Header and footer settings"?

Comment: Good question. I found an alternate tab next to it named 'Snippets' which allowed me to create a shortcode with the PHP and inject this within the html.

Answer (score 0):

Using the alternate tab named Snippets, I injected the PHP field within the html which resolved this issue.